# Copy shell script output to clipboard

Tags: bash, shell

Is there any easy way to implement the copy to clipboard option from the output of a shell script ?

Comment: Do you mean in a portable way?

Comment: Have you tried googling "bash clipboard"?  There seems to be lots of useful information out there.

Comment: Which clipboard? X11 clipboard? Windows clipboard? Mac clipboard? KDE clipboard?

Comment: Are you constrained to terminal only? If not many terminals allow highlighting of output and then use center mouse button to paste. For longer output I'm not sure

Answer (score 63, accepted):

That may depend on the environment you're using. With Gnome at least (I haven't tried the others but it may work), you can pipe your output as follows:

```
echo 123 | xclip
echo 123 | xclip -sel clip
```

The first goes to the mouse clipboard, the second to the "normal" clipboard.

Comment: of course keep in mind that xclip isn't always distributed and installed by default, so you may not want to use it unless you are sure your client has it. Future readers may want to check to see if  xclip's source can be used in the scripting environment OR find a script that does this, even if it is in perl or something at least perl is installed on most distros by default.

Comment: ALSO: its worth noting that "xclip -sel clip" the first letter is only used with -sel, that means you can just use "xclip -sel c" of course the options themselves are in non-ambiguity context so you could use: "xclip -se c"

Comment: Slight variation: copy without trailing newline by swapping out `printf` for `echo`. That is, `printf 123 | xclip -sel clip`

Answer (score 45):

You can use `pbcopy` which is native for Mac OS.

Try this command:

```
echo "variable" | pbcopy
```

it will copy the string "variable" into your clipboard.

Comment: Pls use `-n` for `echo` so it doesn't add a newline at the end of copied text.

Answer (score 14):

If you do that on Windows 10 LXXS Ubuntu bash you can do following command, working also on WSL2.

*Copy from WSL to Windows Clipboard*

```
echo "What so ever..." | clip.exe
```

---

The other way around piping the Windows clipboard to WSL can be done with help of the PowerShell. It has a command called `Get-Clipboard` and a nice short alias `gcb`.

*Paste inside WSL from Windows Clipboard*

```
powershell.exe -Command gcb | cat
```

If you use this more often you could create an alias in the bash like

```
alias wcopy="powershell.exe -Command gcb"
```

and then quickly use as

```
wcopy | cat
```

Comment: It works! Thank you
I've also adds with sudo version this command

Comment: WSL2 did not exist back then, but also works with WSL2.

Comment: And how do I do the other way around? I.e. pipe the contents of a Windows clipboard into a script in WSL/WSL2?

Comment: `clip.exe: command not found`

Comment: @Michael Quite impossible. It is part of Windows commands. https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/clip

Comment: I had to specify the full path as given in another answer.

Comment: @Michael Add that path to the path environment. Then there's no need to specifiy it on every call.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `xclip` command.

```
 echo hello | xclip
```

Instructions for obtaining `xclip` are [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/xclip-linux-insert-files-command-output-intoclipboard/).

Answer (score 5):

`echo` prints a newline at the end as well. Incase anyone else hits the same issue, I used Mauro's approach but with the `printf` command so that it's just the string, no extra line:

For Mac:

```
printf "$YOUR_VAR" | pbcopy
```

Answer (score 1):

With **WSL2** and **sudo** you can use this:

```sh
echo "What so ever..." | /mnt/c/Windows/System32/clip.exe
```