# Grep to Clipboard

Tags: linux, grep, copy

I constantly use grep command on linux servers to search through a directory containing log files. For example I would use

grep -R "123456789"

However sometimes the log related to the grepped string is too big for Putty preventing me from being able to view the whole log. Is there a way to easily copy the grepped log statements to the clipboard so I can paste them elsewhere?

Something like CopyToClipboard(grep -R "123456789")

Comment: Are you connecting from MSWin through Putty? Do you want to populate your Windows clipboard with the output of a remote linux command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shell script output to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023703/shell-script-output-to-clipboard)

Comment: that is correct I want to populate my windows clipboard with output of a remote linux command. I know this can be done through highlighting but the file is to big to highlight the whole thing.

Comment: Im assuming xclip would work but I dont have the rights to download software onto production servers so itll be a moment until I know, Thanks Cyrus

Answer (score 0):

You can find old modified putty versions with Windows Clipboard interfacing on the Internet, but it doesn't seem to be the ideal solution. Maybe `kitty` supports the Windows Keyboard Integration but the function is not documented.

If you just want to read your logs, you can pipe ( `|` ) the `grep -r` output in a pager like `less` or `most`. There, you'll be able to navigate trough the logs with arrow keys and exit with the `q` key. You may want to read `less` and/or `most` manuals for advanced search functions, syntax highlighting, ...

```
grep -r "123456789" | less
```

If you really need to get the full output on your local machine, you can write `stdout` (what grep show you) into a file and retrieve it later with `scp` or `sftp`.

```
grep -r "123456789" > /path/to/my/log/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `xsel -ib`, e.g.

```
grep -R "123456789" | xsel -ib
```

On my distribution `xsel` seems to be installed by default. If not, try

```
sudo apt install xsel
```